# calculating confidence intervals for a probability outcome

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling, confidence-interval

Suppose you have two possible outcomes, $0$ or $1$. You want to determine the probability of getting a $1$, and have confidence intervals on your answer.

E.g. for $10$ runs you might have

$$ \text{experimental results} = 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.$$

Directly from the results you could calculate the probability (mean) of getting a $1$, $pr(1) = 0.9$.

For the confidence interval, how would you calculate the standard deviation or standard error?

Would it be based on the raw data? E.g. in Excel $\text{stdev}(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)$

Or based on the running mean (probability) of the responses. E.g. $\text{stdev}(0, 0.5, 0.667, ..., 0.9)$

I believe it should be based on the variation in the running mean as this is the probability I am interested in, but I'm having a mental blank on trying to justify it. If I wasn't interested in the probability I would just calculate the standard error directly from the results, not after taking the mean - the extra step is throwing me off.

Comment: Sorry I am not getting your question. I have not heard about using "running mean" to estimate the standard deviation. You are trying to construct a confidence interval for the proportion, which is a well-studied problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval There are a several ways, and the most famous one is the normal approximation one. If you think your problem is different from that, you need to further clarify it.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I didn't know what search terms o use for this. That answers my question.